# Thymeleaf form validation for unique value, how to pass error to view

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating register form for my application. I want to check if username is unique. I do it by

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult){


    if (bindingResult.hasErrors() || !userService.isUniqueUsername(user)) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/createnew");
        modelAndView.addObject(bindingResult.getFieldErrors());
        ObjectError objectError = new ObjectError("ERROR", "Username exists!");
        bindingResult.addError(objectError);
        return "user-create";
    }
```

I understand my logic is false here because i dont give the bindingresult to "user-create" view.

```
<div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}">
    <p class="bg-danger text-center">Username error!</p>
</div>
```

So atm i can only show errors from annotations like @NotNull and @Size
But how can i pass info to view that server said username is not unique?

Comment: The fact is you only have a general error you aren't binding it to the `username` field. So actually everything works but the way you are registering the error is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of ObjectError use FieldError object and add it to the binding result. 
Validation:

```
if (influence.getInfluenceImage() == null || influence.getInfluenceImage().isEmpty()) {
    FieldError error = new FieldError("addInfluenceDTO", "influenceImage",
                                      "Influence Image should not be empty.");
    bindingResult.addError(error);
}
```

In my View:

```
<label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('influenceImage')}" th:class="'error'" th:errors=*{influenceImage} class="col-lg-4 control-label" style="color:red;" ></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your error to any field you want

```
if (!form.getUsername().isEmpty() && accountService.exists(form.getUsername()))
      bindingResult.rejectValue("username", "error.username", "Username exists!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to get your goal should be do your custom validation, then the page flow will continue being the same.

Here I will share you a link of how to create your own validation (Is just create an annotation and implement the isValid method)

http://codetutr.com/2013/05/29/custom-spring-mvc-validation-annotations/